# Creating a linked list that represents a deck of cards

Tags: c, linked-list

I need some serious help. My most recent coding assignment requires us to use linked lists to simulate a card game (Crazy 8's). I can do this while using an array to simulate the deck, but I cannot figure out linked lists for the life of me. This is the structure we have to use:

```
typedef struct card_s {
    char suit;
    int face;
    struct card_s *listp; 
} card;
```

However, within this we need three lists: one for the computer's hand, one for the user's hand, and the last as the actual deck. I have tried understanding the basics of linked lists but once I try and apply it to this scenario everything gets confused.

How do I even create the deck of cards and simulate the card game? How do I create three separate lists with this one data structure? All the tutorials I have found online don't exactly answer any of the questions I have. I'm sorry these questions are so general - I am truly lost. Any guidance would be helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why use `int face` when you only need `face` up to 13?

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 why not? `int` is the fastest integer type on a platform. That is the least of Christina's problems.

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 Trying to pack the cards into smaller, slower integer types is a perfect example of premature optimization, which, as you know, Knuth calls "the root of all evil".

Comment: One thing to note in your code: you've got 4 `if` statements with *equivalent* contents, except for the *suit* character; would be easier to order this to do `if (j == 0) { suit = 'H'; }` and so on followed by the card creation with `card_create(currObj, suit, i, NULL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your card creation and deck creation are working well. Writing the entire game of Crazy 8s is beyond the scope of this site, and I don't know the rules anyway, but I will provide general guidance.

You have a linked list for the deck. The head and tail are pointed to by headObj and lastObj. Now you need to create a similar list for a player's hand, which should be initially empty. After that, you need to simulate 'drawing' a random card from the deck. You should write a method for that. It should pick a random card in the deck and remove it (making sure to update the pointers to the cards currently in the deck so that the card you are 'drawing' is now gone) and return the card being removed. Then you can call that method however many times you need (adding the returned card to a player's hand) to fill up a player's hand.

Once you have the players hands and the deck, from there you will want to look into the specific rules of Crazy 8s. Do people draw more cards? You already have a method for that. Do they play cards? You will need to write more methods for that.

Good luck, and if you have any more specific issues trying what I said, feel free to post again and I will try to help.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful!! I do have two more questions though - how would I go about shuffling the deck? I know we can switch nodes within the list but I am not sure about the format of that. Also, how would I make it so I can print "Jack of D", Queen, King etc.

Comment: For printing, just use an if statement in your card_Print() method. Something like if(thisNode->face == 11) {printf("Jack of %c

Comment: For shuffling the deck, I think perhaps the easiest (but not the most efficent) would just be to draw a random card each time instead of shuffling. I.e. in your draw card method, generate a random number from 0 to 51 and then move to the next card in the deck that many times before returning the last one you land on.

Answer (score 1):

nhouser9 answered the linked list question quite well.

To print descriptive card names, you simply need to expand your `card_Print` function.

```
char *faces[] = {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};

void card_Print(card* thisNode)
{
    char *suit;
    switch (thisNode->suit) {
        case 'D':
            suit = "Diamonds";
            break;
        case 'C':
            suit = "Clubs";
            break;
        case 'H':
            suit = "Hearts";
            break;
        case 'S':
            suit = "Spades";
            break;
    }
    printf("%s of %s", faces[thisNode->face - 1], suit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked couple of questions and I'm trying to walk through it:

1- You want to print **King of Hearts** instead of **13 of H**:

you should modify your card_Print like follows:

```
void card_Print(card* thisNode) {
   char face[6];
   char* suit;
   if(thisNode->suit == 'H')
      suit = "Hearts";
   else if(thisNode->suit == 'C')
      suit = "Clubs";
   ...

   if(thisNode->face == 11)
      strcpy(face, "Jack");
   else if(thisNode->face == 12)
      strcpy(face, "Queen");
   else if(thisNode->face == 13)
      strcpy(face, "King");
   else if(thisNode->face == 1)
      strcpy(face, "Ace");
   else
      sprintf(face,"%d",thisNode->face);

   printf("%s of %s\n", face, suit);
   return;
}
```

2- You want to create a deck of card (and shuffle it)

actually you already have your deck in your program with the nested for loops but the question is how you want to shuffle it.

Since you are using a linked list to store your cards, you need to implement a remove_card(int i) method so you can traverse your linked list and remove the ith card from your list:

```
card* remove_card(card* head, int index)
{
   //implement this method
}
```

now you need a random generator to generate random numbers to let you pick one random card from your deck:

```
int remaining = 52;
time_t t;
srand((unsigned) time(&t));

for(int i=0;i<number_of_cards_you_want_to_draw;i++)
{
   card* drawcard = remove_card(head,rand()%remaining);
   //now you can add this draw card to opponents hands linkedlist
   remaining--;
}
```

3 - You want to create three hands:

you can create it very simple with arrays:

```
card* hands[3]; //contains the head pointer for each hand
```

Comment: You can't `sprintf` to `face` since it's an uninitialized pointer. You'd need to allocate a buffer first.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am starting to get a hang of this!